# How do I uninstall SSDTBI for VS 2013/SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I recently installed the client tools for SQL Server 2016. This seemed to hose the COM classes for SSIS in my VS 2013 install, as well as my SSMS 2014 install.

I get a `COM class not found {guid}` error. I don't have a screenshot because I have since uninstalled VS 2013. I've uninstalled SQL Server 2014 as well. The problem is I'm pretty sure SSDTBI is still installed somewhere, and it does not have an entry in the control panel.

I don't want to waste my time installing VS 2013 again if those templates and everything are still going to be there.

Running the SSDTBI installer shows the SSDTBI features as grayed out (meaning they are already installed) and offers no option to remove.

Does anyone know what files are installed and their locations? I really would like to do a clean install.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - After googling some more and seeing all the code for command line installs - I had a revelation that worked:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=UNINSTALL
```

Did the trick.